# Modify all outbound links created on my MediaWiki's pages?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm a developer hosting a private MediaWiki site. I noticed that when you're creating or editing a page, it will automatically change link text into an actual hyperlink (such as http:// linkexample.com/this/is/an/example/ - if I removed the space, StackOverflow would have turned that into a link, just like MediaWiki). I would like to change all occurrences of these outbound hyperlinks so that they go to a redirect script hosted on my site for tracking purposes, instead of directly to the outbound link. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media Wiki Code Docs: http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/

Developing Extensions: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions

Hooks: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks

Hooks - Linker/MakeExternalLinks: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LinkerMakeExternalLink